# Kentico Custom Form control type: I want to give an user input with special characters to search for it

Tags: kentico

I have tried text box as form control type and it didn't work for "xxx & xxxx". So looking for suggestions if it is with Form control type or something else.If yes, please do let me know to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smart Search (i.e.Lucene)  supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The special characters are:  `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`. To escape these characters use the `\` before the character. So try `"xxx \& xxxx"` and see if it works.

Comment: thanks @PeterMogilnitski. i have tried using "xxx \& xxxx". It is not working. https://i.stack.imgur.com/shLMy.png .Have a look at this picture. assume Field or searchName is formated as "xxx & xxxx". so what do you suggest for Documentname it should find results for searchname.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @PeterMogilnitski. i have tried using "xxx \& xxxx". It is not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9zLh.png) Have a look at this picture. assume Field or searchName is formated as "xxx & xxxx". so what do you suggest for Documentname it should find results for searchname.